# Сортировка списка данных из bd java

Tags: java

Есть вот такой код. Он выбирает из базы данные за 24 часа. Задача - найти в выдаче 5 одинаковых значений, если такие имеются. Заранее прошу прошения, если это простая задача. Я новичок.

```
Connection con = getConnection();
    String query = "SELECT Phone FROM sms.log WHERE date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 hour)";


    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String Phone = rs.getString("Phone");
            System.out.println(Phone);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Одинаковых значений чего? Какого поля?

Comment: После выдачи получаем список телефонных номеров за сутки. В списки надо найти одинаковые номера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо изменить запрос:

```
String query = "SELECT Phone FROM sms.log WHERE date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 hour)
         order by Phone asc";
```

В переводе на русский - выдача будет отсортирована по номерам телефонов в порядке возрастания.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Это только часть решения. Потребует дополнительной логики на стороне Java. Результат можно получить одним запросом с подзапросом. Сначала группируем телефоны и считаем количество, потом из этой выборки берём группы, у которых count == 5. ключевые слова для поиска знаний: SQL, GROUP BY, COUNT, SQL подзапросы